# Pairs $(x,y)$ such that $3x-1$ is divisible by $y$ and $3y-1$ is divisible by $x$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How many possible pairs of integers $x$ and $y$ exist such that $3x-1$ is divisible by $y$ and $3y-1$ is divisible by $x$?

---

Since $y| 3x-1$, there exists some $k$ such that $3x-1 = ky$.

On the other hand since $x| 3y-1$ we have $3y-1 = lx$ for some $l$.

i.e. $9y-3 = l(3x) = l(ky+1)$ which implies $(9-kl)y = l+3$.

---

I am not able to procced further.

Any hints will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The absolute values possible for $k$ and $l$ are limited because the divisibility causes $|x/y|$ to be between $1/3$ and $3$ "roughly", so $|10x|$ is "roughly" greather than $|3y|$, so $10$ and above are not possible values for $l$. This is "roughly" because negative $x$ and $y$ complicate the issue a bit, but the general idea should still work. You can see that in your last equation where "large" values of $|k|$ mean $|9-kl| > |l+3|$.

Comment: Have you done a search?  Quick check (on small  natural numbers) finds $(1,1), (1,2), (2,5), (5,7), (4,11)$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel  Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying the two divisibility relations together gives
$$xy\mid(3x-1)(3y-1)=9xy-3(x+y)+1\implies xy\mid3(x+y)-1$$
Now neither $x$ nor $y$ can be zero, since the original relations would then force $3x-1=3y-1=0$ which is impossible for integral $x,y$, so the quotient $\frac{3(x+y)-1}{xy}$ exists and is an integer with absolute value at least $1$. If we then assume without loss of generality that $|x|\ge|y|$, $-6\le y\le5$:

[image]

This means we can get all solutions by checking each possibility for $y$ in turn, which is easy since $x$ must then be a factor of the fixed integer $3y-1$. The solutions with $|x|\ge|y|$ are
$$(x,y)\in\{(-8, -5), (-13, -4), (-7, -2), (7, -2), (-4, -1), (-2, -1), (-1, -1), (1, -1), (2, -1), (4, -1), (-2, 1), (-1, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (-5, 2), (5, 2), (11, 4), (7, 5)\}$$